# Sorting nvarchar column SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

When sorting a nvarchar column in SQL that has a numeric value, SQL Server returns bad sorting and I don't know why!

Is there any particular way SQL Server sorts varchar columns having numeric values?

Thanks

Comment: nvarchar columns will be sorted **as strings** - the sorting isn't **bad** - it's that way by design. If you have numeric values - store them in a numeric column!

Comment: Also if a numeric value is stored as nvarchar, sorting it as int may not be ideal. These values are usually concatenated and has different meaning then simply ascending or descending.

Answer (score 3):

This has a fail-safe which will take into account non numerical values, and place them at the end of your result set.

```
SELECT [nvarcharColumn]
FROM [Table]
ORDER BY CAST(ISNULL(NULLIF(ISNUMERIC([nvarcharColumn]),0),2147483647) as INT)
```

Comment: isnumeric isn't a great function though -- it returns true on certain symbols, not just numbers.  Maybe that's ok for the ordering he wants though.  Nice job on the failsafe though -- most of the other answers missed that little detail...  :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you want it sorted as numbers, you will have to convert it to numbers.

Check here is a list of numbers in an `nVarChar` column being sorted:

```
With MyTable AS
(
    Select Cast ('1' as nVarChar) nVarCharColumn UNION 
    Select '100' UNION
    Select '99'
)
Select *
From MyTable
Order by 1
```

Logically 99 should come before the 100, right? But it is sorted on nVarChar at a time, so the first 1 of the 100 is smaller than the first 9 and therefore it comes before 99.

```
nVarCharColumn
------------------------------
1
100
99

(3 row(s) affected)
```

If you CAST then you get the desired output

```
With MyTable AS
(
    Select Cast ('1' as nVarChar) nVarCharColumn UNION 
    Select '100' UNION
    Select '99'
)
Select *
From MyTable
Order by CAST (nVarCharColumn as Int)
```

Here is the proper output

```
nVarCharColumn
------------------------------
1
99
100

(3 row(s) affected)
```

Here's a twist in the table. What if there is a string value in the column as well?

```
;With MyTable AS
(
    Select Cast ('1' as nVarChar) nVarCharColumn UNION 
    Select '100' UNION
    Select '99' UNION
    Select 'String Value'
)
Select *
From MyTable
Order by CAST (nVarCharColumn as Int)
```

Error!!

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 22
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'String Value' to data type int.
```

So then the `SORT` part checks `IsNumeric` - no need to do the same thing in the `SELECT` part.

```
With MyTable AS
(
    Select Cast ('1' as nVarChar) nVarCharColumn UNION 
    Select '100' UNION
    Select '99' UNION
    Select 'String Value'
)
Select *
From MyTable
Order by CAST ( Case When ISNUMERIC (nVarCharColumn)=1 Then nVarCharColumn Else -99 End as Int)
```

Get the proper output

```
nVarCharColumn
------------------------------
String Value
1
99
100

(4 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: basically @curt's answer, but very nice explanation.

Answer (score 0):

you can type cast the values in number like int or float

```
SELECT nVarCharValue FROM table ORDER BY CAST(nVarCharValue AS INT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sort value should be converted to a numeric value.

```
ORDER BY CONVERT(INT, YourVarcharCol) ASC
```

Hope this helps,

John

Comment: the column has cahrs and some numeric a mix

Comment: @Hadad see my answer for a solution which will take into account chars and numeric: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775833/sorting-nvarchar-column-sql-server-2005/6775967#6775967